# Small grid with no labels

Tags: diagrams, grids

How do I remove all labeling from a small grid to be used for a math test? I have created the grid with `\graphpaper` but get coordinate labels that I don't want.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

This can be easily done with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Simple grid:

\medskip
\tikz\draw [thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);

More complex grid:

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin, step=0.1, gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \draw [thick, gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: grids]

Answer (score 7):

The venerable `graphpap` package does not provide a command to do that, but it's not hard to write your own command that does what you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphpap}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\graphpapern[1][10]{\leavevmode\@gridn{#1}}
\def\@gridn#1(#2,#3)#4{\@grid@n{#1}{#2}{#3}(}
\def\@grid@n#1#2#3(#4,#5){%
\@tempcnta=#4\relax
\divide\@tempcnta#1\relax
\advance\@tempcnta1\relax
{\thinlines\@nonumvgrid(#2,#3){#1}{\@tempcnta}{#5}
\@tempcnta#4\relax
\divide\@tempcnta5\relax
\divide\@tempcnta#1\relax
\advance\@tempcnta1\relax
\@tempcntb5\relax
\multiply\@tempcntb#1\relax
\thicklines\@nonumvgrid(#2,#3){\@tempcntb}{\@tempcnta}{#5}
\@tempcnta#5\relax
\divide\@tempcnta #1\relax
\advance\@tempcnta1\relax
\thinlines\@nonumhgrid(#2,#3){#1}{\@tempcnta}{#4}
\@tempcnta#5\relax
\divide\@tempcnta5\relax
\divide\@tempcnta#1\relax
\advance\@tempcnta1\relax
\thicklines\@nonumhgrid(#2,#3){\@tempcntb}{\@tempcnta}{#4}}%
\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\graphpapern[10](0,0)(200,200)

\end{document}
```

[image: grid]